# .htacces redirect (wildcard) a subfolder to a https subdomain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a folder named: "polygon" I can access in these ways:

- http://website.com/polygon
- http://www.website.com/polygon

I created a subdomain for this folder and can also access it in two ways:

- http://polygon.website.com
- http://www.polygon.website.com

And I made an https access for this subdomain: https://polygon.website.com

I want to redirect the folder and the subdomain, with and without, *www* to the: https://polygon.website.com

In .htaccess, made with Cpanel, I made a redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^secure\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/polygon\.website\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but I can't redirect the `http://(www.?)website.com/polygon` to the secure url, because of a loop error message...

Thank you for the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude each sub1, sub2 individually like so;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Or just be specific that you only want to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com with the RewriteCond

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Reference

https://serverfault.com/questions/391843/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-and-retain-subdomains-from-redirecting

Comment: thanx for this but for me the important is to redirect wildcard the folder, and subdomain to the secure domain :)

Comment: If I not was clear, I want to redirect domain.com/nothing and nothing.domain.com to secure url: https://nothing.domain.com